# Making a nav menu that becomes sticky as the page scrolls down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navbar

I have two menus in use on a site I'm building. The second menu is a category menu, and I need to make it stick to the top of the page as a user scrolls down the page to view content. I had it working previously, but had to remove some elements from my header. For whatever reason, it won't work now. Code to follow.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function sticky_relocate() {
  var window_top = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
  var div_top = jQuery('#scroller-anchor').offset().top;
  if (window_top > div_top)
    jQuery('#navbar').addClass('sticky')
  else
    jQuery('#navbar').removeClass('sticky');
  }
 jQuery(function() {
  jQuery(window).scroll(sticky_relocate);
  sticky_relocate();
  });</script>
```

And the menu structure looks like this...

```
<div id="scroller-anchor"></div>        
<div id="navbar" class="navbar">                
<nav id="site-navigation" class="navigation main-navigation" role="navigation">                 
    <h3 class="menu-toggle">Menu</h3>                       
        <a class="screen-reader-text skip-link" href="#content" title="Skip to content">Skip to content</a>                         
    <div class="menu-category-menu-container">                              
        <ul id="menu-category-menu" class="nav-menu">                                   
            <li id="menu-item-1408" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-1408">                                     
                <a href="http://108.165.22.98/~forgetel/?cat=12">All</a>                                    
            </li>                                   
            <li id="menu-item-1414" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-1414">                                     
                <a href="http://108.165.22.98/~forgetel/?cat=5">Videos</a>                                  
            </li>                                   
            <li id="menu-item-1409" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-1409">                                     
                <a href="http://108.165.22.98/~forgetel/?cat=6">Entertainment</a>                                   
            </li>                                   
            <li id="menu-item-1412" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-1412">                                     
                <a href="http://108.165.22.98/~forgetel/?cat=8">Politics</a>                                    
            </li>                                   
            <li id="menu-item-1413" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-1413">                                     
                <a href="http://108.165.22.98/~forgetel/?cat=9">Sports</a>                                  
            </li>                                   
            <li id="menu-item-1410" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-1410">                                     
                <a href="http://108.165.22.98/~forgetel/?cat=10">Fashion</a>                                    
            </li>                                   
        </ul>                           
    </div>                                          
</nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
</div>
```

Help?

*EDIT*

Forgot to include what was in the sticky class.

```
.sticky {
position: fixed;
top: 0; 
}
```

*EDIT2*

Attempted the following fix, still to no avail.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var position_to_make_nav_sticky = jQuery('#scroller-anchor').offset().top; //get the Y-position of section 
jQuery(window).on({ scroll:function(){ // fires when user scrolls 
var current_position = window.pageYOffset; // get the current window Y-Position 
if( current_position > position_to_make_nav_sticky )
 { jQuery('#navbar').addClass('sticky'); // add class to make the nav sticky using css
 } else { jQuery('#navbar').removeClass('sticky'); // remove sticky css class } });
</script>
```

Comment: What's in your CSS sticky class that you mention?

Comment: Have a look at the source code of this demo page.  Its what I used for mine  =)  http://jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/fixedfloat.html

Comment: you're missing a closing } after your function.

Comment: I reviewed the site linked, but I still don't see where mine is broken... I'm horrid at js, but this should be something simple, shouldn't it?

Comment: I don't see the missing }, care to point it out?

Comment: Witch browser are you trying? I think this could be trick in IE7 and previous. In `Compatibility Mode` too.

Comment: I'm using chrome, I had it working before in all major browsers though.

Answer (score 0):

for anyone interested in making a sticky nav on scroll:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var position_to_make_nav_sticky = jQuery('#scroller-anchor').offset().top; //get the Y-position of section

    jQuery(window).on({
        scroll:function(){ // fires when user scrolls
            var current_position = window.pageYOffset; // get the current window Y-Position
            if( current_position > position_to_make_nav_sticky ) {
                jQuery('#navbar').addClass('sticky'); // add class to make the nav sticky using css
            } else {
                jQuery('#navbar').removeClass('sticky'); // remove sticky css class
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I tried this, replacing 'section' and 'nav' with 'navbar', and swapping the '$' for 'jQuery' since WP has issues with '$'. Doesn't work for me.

Comment: just in case, did you replace nav with "navbar" or "#navbar"?

Comment: "navbar" ... does it need to be "#navbar"?

Comment: what about the 'section' did you change to scroller-anchor or #scroller-anchor?

Comment: Changed it to #scroller-anchor, still not it

Comment: looks like this currently: <script type="text/javascript">
var position_to_make_nav_sticky = jQuery('#scroller-anchor').offset().top;  //get the Y-position of section

jQuery(window).on({
  scroll:function(){ // fires when user scrolls
    var current_position = window.pageYOffset;  // get the current window Y-Position
    if( current_position > position_to_make_nav_sticky ) {
      jQuery('#navbar').addClass('sticky');  // add class to make the nav sticky using css
    } else {
      jQuery('#navbar').removeClass('sticky');  // remove sticky css class
  }
});</script>

Comment: I don't know if this will help or not, but here is the site link: http://108.165.22.98/~forgetel

Comment: I forgot a closing brace for scroll:function.  copy and try again.

Comment: It still isn't working, though I noticed that you have a "(" after "jQuery(window).on" that doesn't close, I tried closing it in multiple places, to no avail.

Comment: I don't know why it isn't working for me then... any chance you could take a peak at the site and help me out? I'm getting this "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { "

Comment: it's because it's missing a closing } before the )};